# 100's of Vertices all with different Y Coordinates need to be moved to same Y coordinate plane

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

All these vertices have different Y coordinates yet when I select them all, I cannot move all of them to the same plane of a Y coordinate. How can I move all of them without tedious work?[image]

Comment: This may be related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/move-align-one-vertex-on-a-non-planar-face-to-make-it-planar. In short - scale them all by Z to 3D cursor location, which should be placed on your plane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To scale all vertices to conform to a certain "plane" in a direction (Y axis), select all the vertices you want to move.

Place the 3D cursor anywhere along the Y plane you want (IE place the cursor's Y position to the position you want your vertices to move to and ignore its Z and X position).

Change the pivot point to `3D cursor`

[image: 3d Cursor Pivot]

Press `s` to enable scale mode, then press `y` to restrict scaling in the Y axis. Scale "down" to as close to 0 as possible, or type `0`. All the vertices will snap to the cursor's Y position while maintaining their original X and Z coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Select all your veritces and scale to zero <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]