# subdivision surface pulls the shape wrongly

Tags: modeling

This subdivision surface modifier is somehow approaching the result I am after except for the obvious pulls, I hope you can see the "tenting" effect i would like to get rid of

[image]

Comment: This caused by an n-gon, or series of n-gons and tris

Comment: so it is because i made the object free hand rather than making it out of polygons?

Comment: and if I join the shapes into regular polygons it wont stretch anymore?

Comment: The issue is that you have a lot of non-panar geometry. You have to re-arrange the topology of your model. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane

Comment: got ya nice one cheers. back to the drawing board. I think I am getting the idea though