# Forcing randomized quads to stay coplanar?

Tags: modifiers

I have a lot of quads on a grid, which will get displaced by a Displace modifier with a noise texture. This is my current result:
[image]

As you can see, quads aren't deformed in a way that will make them stay coplanar.

Is there any way to solve this, either with modifiers or a script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the displace modifier on each tile? Would need to apply the modifier before using the fixes in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane  Otherwise you could make a row x col grid, put the displace mod on that and dupli-face a plane from it.

Comment: @batFINGER can you explain the dupli-face ? I tried it but it was not good

Comment: @batFINGER, sorry, never mind... it is ok...

Comment: the solution given by @batFINGER in image : https://i.gyazo.com/c2df56c47215630d12c2239a4146a93a.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @batFINGER said, you can use dupli-face.

Create a plane and parent it to your displaced mesh (the one you shown in picture).

[image: Set this selected mesh parented to your displaced mesh]

In the object properties of your displaced mesh, go to the duplication panel and select "Faces" (the blue button on the bottom part of the picture).

[image]

And.... that's all...

On the left, the "tri deformed original mesh", on the right "only planar quads"

(again, thanks to @batFINGER comment)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is a particle system on the vertices of a high density mesh.  Since the particle system is after the displace modifier, only the location of the object particles are affected.  Internal vertices of the object particles are not affected.