# How to make faces planar without distorting other faces?

Tags: mesh

other than not creating non-planar faces in the first place, which is tedious for a beginner like me. Is there any way to make a face planar but not mess up the connected faces?

All I've managed to find for flattening faces is "select face, set scale to zero on axis" 
Which works... but only for that face, it will mis-align the vertices of another connected face almost always.

Maybe something to force all faces to be planar by not allowing you to move vertices so they'd cause it to be non planar?

I'm having so much trouble modelling and having none messed up derpy faces.

Comment: imho, a nonplanar is so because its vertices cannot form a planar faces in their current position. so, to make that face planar, you have to move at least one of those vertex. But any face sharing that vertex will be affected by the move too, of course. Other than accepting this, you can only create more geometry and split that nonplanar face into at least two planar faces (if and how possible)

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/how-to-make-all-quads-or-ngons-on-your-mesh-planar-2d and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane

Comment: It could sound off-topic but I would suggest that you should (especially as a beginner) try and go for proper quad topology. It could be tedious but it will pay off later for sure and you'll have less problems.

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56755/flat-quads-or-why-is-my-mesh-so-funky/56764#56764

Comment: @LukeD How would I go about doing quad topology properly though?

Comment: Here is a good starting point with some neat tips: http://topologyguides.com/. Also look for things like Edge Flow or Retopology. Don't look specifically about Blender, because no matter what software you will use - good topology is good. I don't know how you mesh looks like so I can't give you more detailed help.

Comment: @LukeD Well thanks, I'll take a look at it~