# Odd shadows being cast

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shadows, lighting

I've got a fairly simple shape, and when I render it in cycles I notice some odd shadows being cast across part of the faces.

[image: Model with shadows]

Here are some images of my wireframe - what could be causing the green-encircled shadows?

[image: Front wireframe]

[image: Side wireframe]

[image: Off-rear wireframe]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flatten a non-planar face to a targeted plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane)

Comment: you are most likely dealing with non-planar faces. Your topology looks really clean and nice, but the weirdly shaded faces might be non-planar, so the triangulation made by the renderer becomes visible. Take a look at the link above, that should fix your shading issues.

Comment: @yann https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Comment: @yann I've made the faces planar but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @jamesmonger please upload your file. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have smooth shading active? If that's the problem, try marking some edges as sharp, use the "Auto Smooth"-option in the object data panel or split some edges.

Comment: I'm not using smooth shading