# Rendered image background has strange stripes

Tags: rendering, workbench-render-engine

I have created a little scene. However, the right half of the image produced has white/grey stripes in the background. What is causing this? I am using the *Workbench* render engine.

[image: Blender render]

I believe this is caused by a `plane` which is flat with the grid (hidden in the image).

Comment: it could be a non-planar face https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane#35763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be a glitch, but deleting the `plane` flat with the grid and adding it again fixed the issue.